# Is it possible to get novels written in Chinese and English on the same page to download?

Tags: books

Is anyone aware of where I can find novels for download which contain both English and Chinese on the same page?

Comment: For anyone providing an answer please do not provide links to sites which may contain copyright or otherwise illegal content. A more helpful answer is a guide to how to find these types of sites (what search terms etc.) rather than linking to a site which may expire.

Comment: English and Chinese translations of Franz Kafka's 2 well known novels available free on web, 
Franz Kafka，The Trial (Der Prozeß) http://www.sparknotes.com/lit/trial/section1.rhtml   Chinese：http://www.my285.com/wgwx/zpj/kafuka/sp/The Metamorphosis (Die Verwandlung) http://history-world.org/The_Metamorphosis_T.pdf http://www.xiaoshuotxt.net/waiwen/9652/543366.html

Comment: why on the same page, isn't on the same screen good enough? 为何要在同一面页上，在同一个屏幕上这就不好了吗？

Comment: Take a look at http://ctext.org/

Answer (score 1):

I think the moderator hit the nail on the head here by pointing out that we want to help you to be able to find what you are looking for, which often comes down to having the right keywords, i found that 漢英對照 works rather well

All of Jane Eyre (which is public domain) complete with English MP3's co.mes up along with others when searching google for the following search terms: 漢英對照小說 在線.

I'd be curious to hear more about what you are looking to do with the back-to-back texts.  If it is to read through and learn to read in Chinese, by using the English to refer to, I would do so sparingly as the books you're most likely to find in this format are English texts translated into Chinese, so translations, not real Chinese" and they'll be devoid of many culturally relevant common expressions such as 你吃了嗎?

Depending on your level, and what you are aiming to accomplish, I would suggest you may also consider parallel texts, i.e texts on the same topic, but not translations of each other (they really stressed this in interpreting school).  This will keep things in context for you and allow you do develop a more organic language base that will be more naturally and with more pizzazz.  For an interpreter, reading parallel texts allows them to focus on complete ideas rather than words.

There are actually many more advantages on parallel readings versus translations, perhaps for a later discussion.

Best of luck!

Answer (score -1):

I have a copy of Jane Austen's Pride and Prejudice. It has Chinese on odd pages and English on even pages. Such books are cheap and you can buy them in most big book shops in China.